# How to determine overlaps between selection ranges in a grid of items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, range, normalization

Imagine something like a grid of items.
The user can select multiple ranges of items in the grid. When there are multiple ranges (selections), I want to determine wether the last created range overlaps with an existing range.
The grid system can be compared with characters in a textarea, where it is possible to highlight multiple text ranges.

- Every single range always exists of adjacent items, next to each
  other, or the first item in the next row in the grid. (Also totally
  similar to selecting text in a text document.)
- When the user creates a range, it can overlap with an existing range, or even totally fit into an existing range.

A range is stored in memory as:

```
{
    'rangeStartLineIndex': 2,
    'rangeStartColIndex': 9,
    'rangeEndLineIndex': 4,
    'rangeEndColIndex': 7
}
```

Above range can be visualized as in the image. But note that the number of rows and columns of the grid is not constant.

[image]

The goal is to loop through the existing ranges, and look if the just created range overlaps with (or totally fits in) an existing range. If so, then take that existing range, and extend it so the created range merges with the one it overlaps with. So, it's kind of normalizing data.

Another example in code:

```
var ranges = []; // stores the range objects that are created earlier.
var createdRange = {...}; // range object just created.

for(var i = 0; i < ranges; i++) {
    var overlap = doesThisOverlap(createdRange, ranges[i]);

    if(overlap) {

        // overlaps, which means we extend the existing range.
        range[i].rangeStartLineIndex = Math.min(range[i].rangeStartLineIndex, createdRange.rangeStartLineIndex);
        range[i].rangeStartColIndex = Math.min(range[i].rangeStartColIndex, createdRange.rangeStartColIndex);
        range[i].rangeEndLineIndex = Math.max(range[i].rangeEndLineIndex, createdRange.rangeEndLineIndex);
        range[i].rangeEndColIndex = Math.max(range[i].rangeEndColIndex, createdRange.rangeEndColIndex);

    } else {
        // means the new range does not extend an existing range, so add it.
        ranges.push(createdRange);
    }
}

function doesThisOverlap(rangeA, rangeB) {
    // ???
}
```

When trying to implement the function `doesThisOverlap`, I end up with an excessive amount of if-blocks. I get confused, also because I've got the feeling there's an algorithm found for this.

What I also tried is adding up a range startpoint's line and col index to give it a 'score', (and do the same for its endpoint's line and column index).
Then compare that startpoint/endpoint scores between the ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not really 2D, it becomes much easier if you represent the range as

```
{
  rangeStart: 29,
  rangeEnd:48
}
```

You can convert to this representation by calculating

```
lineIndex * COLUMN_NUMBER + columnIndex.
```

You should basically iterate all ranges and find min rangeStart and rangeEnd. Then you can convert the result to column/row using:

```
columnIndex = x % COLUMN_NUMBER;
lineIndex = parseInt(x / COLUMN_NUMBER).
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to identify whether the `createdRange` overlaps with one of the `ranges` is to give each `range` start index and end index and then, check whether the indices of `createdRange` overlaps with indices of any other range or not.

First, Let us change the shape of the `range` object from better readability:

```
{
    start: { row: 2, col: 9 },
    end: { row: 4, col: 7 }
}
```

Mapping of this `range` object with the one you defined is simple:

```
rangeStartLineIndex => start.row
rangeStartColIndex  => start.col
rangeEndLineIndex   => end.row
rangeEndColIndex    => end.col
```

With this out of the way, I would first point at one little mistake in the logic. 
In the `for` loop, you are checking if the `createdRange` overlaps with the current `range` or not. If not, you are **adding** that `createdRange` to the ranges array. 
However, you only need to add the `createdRange` in the `ranges` **IF none of the ranges overlap with `createdRange`**

Thus, the correct `for` loop would look like:

```
var hasOverlap = false; // this will tell if any of the ranges overlap

for(var i = 0; i < ranges; i++) {
    var overlap = doesThisOverlap(createdRange, ranges[i]);

    if(overlap) {
        // overlaps, which means we extend the existing range.
        // some logic to update the overlapped ranges
        hasOverlap = true; // a range has overlapped, set the flag to true
        break;

    }
}
// Did we see any overlap?
if(!hasOverlap) {
    // no we did not, let us add this range to ranges array
    // means the new range does not extend an existing range, so add it.
    ranges.push(createdRange);
}
```

---

Alright, now let us see how to calculate the indices for the given range. 
If we start assigning indices (starting from 0) from left to right in the grid, 
simple math says that the index of the box in the row `r` and in the column `c` will be:

```
index = r * (COL + 1) + c [COL is the total number of columns in the grid]
```

Here are the helper functions which will help to calculate the indices given the range:

```
function getIndex(row, col, COL) {
    return row * (COL + 1) + col;
}

function getIndices(range) {
    var start = range.start;
    var end = range.end;

    var startIndex = getIndex(start.row, start.col, COLS);
    var endIndex = getIndex(end.row, end.col, COLS);

    return { start: startIndex, end: endIndex };
}
```

Note that `getIndices` takes a `range` and outputs an object with `start` and `end` indices. We can now calculate indices for `createdRange` and current `range`. And based on the indices, we would know whether the ranges overlap or not.

---

The problem now boils down to this:
We have a line AB, and given a new line PQ, find out whether the new line PQ overlaps AB or not. ( where A,B,P,Q are points on the number line, A < B and P < Q ). 
Take pen and paper and draw a few lines. You will come to know that there only two condition when the lines **will not** overlap:

> Either Q < A  or   B < P

Mapping this observations to our `range` object, we can say that:

```
P => createdRange.startIndex
Q => createdRange.endIndex

A => currentRange.startIndex
B => currentRange.endIndex
```

This is how it would look in the code:

```
var createdRangeIndices = getIndices(createdRange);
var hasOverlap = false;

for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var currentRangeIndices = getIndices(ranges[i]);
    var overlap = (createdRangeIndices.end < currentRangeIndices.start) 
                    || (currentRangeIndices.end < createdRangeIndices.start);
    if (!overlap) {
        // overlaps, which means we extend the existing range.
        // some logic to update the overlapped ranges
        hasOverlap = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!hasOverlap) {
    // means the new range does not extend an existing range, so add it.
    ranges.push(createdRange);
}
```

Note that we got rid of the function `doesThisOverlap`. A simple flag would do.

All that remains now is the logic to update the `range` if there is an overlap.
A part of which you had already figured out in your question. We take the minimum of the starting index and maximum of the ending index. Here is the code for that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var currentRangeIndices = getIndices(ranges[i]);
    var overlap = (createdRangeIndices.end < currentRangeIndices.start) 
                    || (currentRangeIndices.end < createdRangeIndices.start);
    if (!overlap) {
        // overlaps, which means we extend the existing range.
        // some logic to update the overlapped ranges

        var start, end;
        if (currentRangeIndices.start < createdRangeIndices.start) {
            start = ranges[i].start;
        } else {
            start = createdRange.start;
        }

        if (currentRangeIndices.end > createdRangeIndices.end) {
            end = ranges[i].end;
        } else {
            end = createdRange.end;
        }
        ranges[i] = { start: start, end: end };
        hasOverlap = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And done!

Here is the complete code that combines all the bits and pieces together:

```
var ROWS = 7;
var COLS = 3;

function getIndex(row, col, COL) {
    return row * (COL + 1) + col;
}

function getIndices(range) {
    var start = range.start;
    var end = range.end;

    var startIndex = getIndex(start.row, start.col, COLS);
    var endIndex = getIndex(end.row, end.col, COLS);

    return { start: startIndex, end: endIndex };
}

function addRange(ranges, createdRange) {
    var createdRangeIndices = getIndices(createdRange);
    var hasOverlap = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        var currentRangeIndices = getIndices(ranges[i]);
        var overlap =
            createdRangeIndices.end < currentRangeIndices.start ||
            currentRangeIndices.end < createdRangeIndices.start;
        if (!overlap) {
            var start, end;
            if (currentRangeIndices.start < createdRangeIndices.start) {
                start = ranges[i].start;
            } else {
                start = createdRange.start;
            }
            if (currentRangeIndices.end > createdRangeIndices.end) {
                end = ranges[i].end;
            } else {
                end = createdRange.end;
            }
            ranges[i] = { start: start, end: end };
            hasOverlap = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasOverlap) {
        // means the new range does not extend an existing range, so add it.
        ranges.push(createdRange);
    }
}

var ranges = []; // stores the range objects that are created earlier.
var rangesToAdd = [
    {
        start: { row: 2, col: 1 },
        end: { row: 6, col: 0 }
    },
    {
        start: { row: 6, col: 2 },
        end: { row: 7, col: 2 }
    },
    {
        start: { row: 3, col: 1 },
        end: { row: 6, col: 1 }
    },
    {
        start: { row: 6, col: 1 },
        end: { row: 6, col: 2 }
    }
];

rangesToAdd.forEach(aRange => addRange(ranges, aRange));
console.log(ranges);
```